# .NET NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove does not refresh collection

Tags: .net, observablecollection

The following method removes a range of items from my custom observable collection:

```
 public void RemoveRange(IList items)
        {         

            foreach (T item in items)
            {
                this.Remove(item);            

            }                 
                UpdateProcessingState(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, items));

        }
```

EventHandler for NotifyCollectionChanged simply calls CollectionView.Refresh().   When I do this, removed items are still in my grid.

However, if I remove one item at a time and raise collection change event with this;

```
new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, item)
```

grid refreshes properly.

Did I miss something?

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

CollectionView doesn't properly support the CollectionChanged event when there are multiple items. I get the feeling they didn't implement that since they didn't implement AddRange/RemoveRange into ObservableCollection either.

You can try using the NotificationCollectionChangedAction.Reset instead. Just be wary that there's a performance cost with resets if you're working with huge lists, because anything associated with the collection will have to rebind every item.

Comment: Turns out it must have been something I was doing wrong.  NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, items) works fine.

Comment: @e28Makaveli - Strange because what rossisdead says is right, this shouldn't be working if your actualling binding to something like ListBox. Are you using .NET 4.0? Maybe if so perhaps it has been fixed there? I'm still on .NET 3.5 so I wouldn't know.